# Partner Center Permissions lost

Tags: azure

I'm experiencing a problem with partner center API. When I consent application to be used and I get refresh_token I'm able to start using the partner center API with access_token obtained with the refresh_token obtained before.

After 2 days when I execute the same API calls I start to get a "401" http code on every request. I'm able to get the access_token but any operation against the API with obtained access_token is returning a "401" http code.

Does anyone experienced the same problem?